# BT A2DP not connecting automatically

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed a CSR 4.0 bluetooth dongle with drivers on my PC and paired it with a Bluetooth speaker. It works OK but I have to manually start the A2DP (sink) service for the speaker to work. Is there any way to get this to start automatically when the PC boots?
Ian

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post, and see if it helps

[https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6][1]